# IBM-MQ chart create queues

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, ibm-mq, helmfile

I'm trying to deploy IBM-MQ chart to kubernetes (rancher). I'm using helmfile v.0.141.0 (helm 3, kubectl 1.22.2) to achieve this. What I want to achieve is programmatically create custom queues after deploy. I tried to use helmfile hooks to achieve this, but seems that they're not working (I think they're being executed too early). My helmfile:

```
repositories:
  - name: ibm-stable-charts
    url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable

releases:
  - name: ibm-mq
    labels:
      app: ibm-mq
    namespace: user
    chart: ibm-stable-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev
    hooks:
      - events: [ "cleanup" ]
        showlogs: true
        command: "./script.sh"
    values:
      - license: accept
        image:
          tag: latest
        queueManager:
          dev:
            secret:
              adminPasswordKey: secret
              name: secret
```

You can read [this guide](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ibm-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev) if you want more details on how to recreate this situation. And my `script.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
runmqsc QM1 <<EOF
define qlocal (TEST);
end;
EOF
```

And I see that it's getting executed after helmfile deploys IBM-MQ, but there's no output, even tho loggin is enabled, and if you check logs of the pod, you can see that IBM-MQ takes actually some time to start, and I'm assuming that script is being executed when ibm-mq didn't even start yet (if it's connecting at all, and of course if you check the queues new queues are not here). I tried to add this string to the beginning of the file which I'm using to connect to ibm-mq shell, but it didn' work out too.

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl exec -i -t -n user ibm-mq-0 -c qmgr "--" sh -c "clear; (bash || ash || sh)"
runmqsc QM1 <<EOF ...
```

So, is there any way to create custom queues without creating new image, as [described here?](https://github.com/IBM/charts/blob/master/entitled/ibm-mqadvanced-server-integration-prod/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

The sample MQ container image will automatically process any MQSC files it finds in the `/etc/mqm` directory.  So you can update the Helm chart to put a file from a ConfigMap in that location.  The [new IBM MQ sample Helm chart](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-helm) will do that for you.

Under-the-covers, the container is doing this using the `crtmqm -ic` option, which runs any files in the specified directory at start-up.